# angular 7 getting ActivatedRoute params not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-activatedroute

Hi and thank you for your help in advance.

I have been working on this problem for awhile now and have not been able to figure it out yet.

What I want to do is to access the params and display what is selected on the page.

It doesn't fire when the routerLink is clicked.

so I have the following: 
[question on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1nbn3d?file=src%2Fpolyfills.ts)

I can't seem to get it to work.

**layout.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.scss']
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUrl: string;
  currentLang: string;

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  gettLang(): void {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('lang'));
    this.currentLang = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('lang');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gettLang();
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
      () => this.gettLang()
     );
  }

}
```

**layout.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="[ 'beam/comic', 'de',1,'home', 1 ]">name de</a><br>
<a [routerLink]="[ 'beam/comic', 'en',1,'home', 1 ]">name en</a><br>
<a [routerLink]="[ 'beam/comic', 'sp',1,'home', 1 ]">name sp</a><br>
--- {{ currentUrl }} --- <br>
{{ currentLang }}---
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'beam/comic/:lang/:ep/:title/:page',
    component: LayoutComponent
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    redirectTo: 'beam/comic/en/1/home/1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-layout></app-layout>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'beam';
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material';
import {AllMaterialModule} from './material/material.module';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavBoxComponent } from './nav-box/nav-box.component';
import { ImageBoxComponent } from './image-box/image-box.component';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';
import { LanguageListComponent } from './nav-box/language-list/language-list.component';
import { EpisodeListComponent } from './nav-box/episode-list/episode-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavBoxComponent,
    ImageBoxComponent,
    LayoutComponent,
    LanguageListComponent,
    EpisodeListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AllMaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Thanks Nate

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try accessing the param in the following way instead by accessing this param from the resolved value of the paramMap observable stream rather than the snapshot:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
    (params: ParamMap) => {
      this.currentLang = params.get('lang');
    }
  )
}
```

This is effectively how the official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action) describes working with params

You could always pass the observable stream ParamMap value to the helper function if you wanted for style purposes

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: As I have it, it doesn't work. When I place <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the app.component.html it works~ I am confused.

Comment: Where was your router outlet before? You need a router outlet for the router to work.

Comment: I am on my learning curve for this I think get it now as the route changes the component associated with the router-outlet will render and have access to the params.

Comment: @Natdrip, that was what caused me problems. The router-outlet wasn't nested properly, so it showed the component, but wouldn't get me the params.  Wrapping my component in another router-outlet fixed my issue.

Comment: @Natdrip a nested router-outlet would only be needed if any of your routes use the children property.

Comment: Omg @AlexanderStaroselsky i have been stuck for 4hours with that, everything was exactly like other components.. it need to be 'comp1/comp2/id' where comp1 has <router-outlet>